# Securely storing secrets in hosted source control

Tags: encryption, version-control, dvcs

Our company has recently adopted private repositories hosted by BitBucket over a local source control system. In addition to source code, each repositories have all necessary components to build, configure, and deploy (scripts, etc). This works well in most regards, but I'm torn on what to do with sensitive passwords, ftp configurations, etc that would normally accompany my build and deploy scripts.

See [this similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839141/is-it-considered-good-practice-to-store-passwords-in-a-private-github-repository) outlining the concerns.

In my case, the xml configurations are representative of the code that is used to parse them, so they need to be versioned (schema's anyway).

Clearly, storing secrets on anything other than something local increases your risks, but what are the alternatives? Store them encrypted? Use fancy config section replacements during build, feeding config values in from external system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Git**

Smudge/Clean filters for bidirectional KEYWORD<->CODE replacement

**Mercurial**

MQ-patch (local), which restore sensitive data in local Working Dir, missing in pushed and published repo

Comment: (We're using Hg, so MQ-Patch). So this essentially means the actual values would need to be stored outside of source control? Would this work for entire files like certificates or is just a string replacement?

Comment: @JeremySmith - no, patches in mq-queue stored inside (and as a part of) local repository. And every patch can store **any** changes, which can be performed with working directory by hand (add-remove-rename-edit files)

Comment: I'm no Hg wiz, but if it's part of the local repository, how would changes to these files be shared with other devs without a push?

Comment: @JeremySmith - you **can** exchange patches in P2P-communications (dev-dev) in pull|push (`--mq` option) *or* use [MQCollab Extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MqCollabExtension) *or* save (applied) patch(es) as bundle and transfer bundle in usual way. I'll think MQCollab is the best way (for me)

Answer (score 0):

You could locally store a configuration file with the sensitive data. You should sign this file, which contains a private or secret key. The public key to verify the signature should be stored within the code. Now you store the versioned configuration encrypted within the source repository. The encrypted config can only be read if the application finds the signed decryption key at a specified place. If it cannot find them it falls back to plain defaults for testing. Don't forget to add logging which config you are using if you add this additional trick. You might want to sign or perform a MAC calculation over the configuration files as well.

How much security this delivers depends on the rest of the system, but you can keep relatively static data locally and still put the configuration data within the versioning system. Note that many versioning systems like text, so you might want to base64 encode the encrypted configuration files, just to be sure.

This is just one of many schemes of course.

Comment: I think if we go this route we'll like use RSA Protected Configuration with aspnet_regiis like we've been doing with web.configs. Could this be hooked into the commit process somehow to encrypt the configurations on the way in? Perhaps this is what Lazy Badger's solution would provide?

Comment: Dunno, maybe ask lazy badger. This is a general solution that is more or less independent from the used source control. I'm into crypto and security, not so much version contol systems.