# Dealing with sensitive password data in Perforce

Tags: repository, perforce

What is the best practice for dealing with **files containing sensitive password data** in *Perforce*?

In my team's projects, we are trying to eliminate such files from the repository.

1. Are there any **Perforce specific features/conventions** that could help?
2. There is some xml files which contain code (not just passwords), which need to be under revision control. How are such files handled?

The following posts specific to git seem to be a good starting point:

1. [Remove sensitive data](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data)
2. [Best practices for github](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2397905/640378)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [p4 obliterate](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r12.1/manuals/cmdref/obliterate.html) to remove the offending versions of files containing passwords.  You could use .example files containing example/fake passwords.  Use your favorite scripting language to replace the passwords locally and create the real files.  You could add [p4 protect](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/protect.html) permissions to disallow particular files from being checked in.