# Is it safe and recommended to upload SQL to public git repository?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, git, github

Question above. Technically, things should be fine as long as the website is secured well enough, but still, as a newcomer to git, I feel like it would make it just easier for somebody to compromise my server.

EDIT: By that I mean things like create-statements. The issue is about sharing the table structure of my database with everyone.

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397822/what-is-the-best-practice-for-dealing-with-passwords-in-github

Comment: What do you mean by SQL?

Comment: I edited for better understanding

Comment: why use a public git repo if you are concerned about privacy ?

Answer (score 4):

This would be a case of "security by obscurity". You should treat your table *structure* (not its *contents*, obviously) as public knowledge. You should also be taking care to avoid SQL injection, so knowledge of the table structure isn't abusable.

If it were insecure to know the table structure, every open source project with a DB would be insecure. I can figure out Wikipedia's MySQL structure in a few minutes, but I can't hack Wikipedia because of it.

Answer (score -1):

I think that depends on the project. If it's a personal (study, something smaller or without importance) or open-source, i think it's OK. If you are uploading some company stuff or something that might cause some danger to the application, **don't upload in a public repository**, but you can upload to git anyway.

Comment: OP's question is fundamentally "*might* this cause some danger?", though.