# Hide password in all previous commits on Github repo

Tags: git, github, repository, password-protection, sensitive-data

I have uploaded my project on GitHub public repo. But one of the files contains my password information. And there are several commits I have made already. How can I hide my password right from the initial commit?

There is no separate file for a password. So I can't use .gitignore in this case. A password is hardcoded in the app.py file which handles the main logic of the application. So, I can't use BFG Repo-Cleaner. Is it possible to delete the file and add a new one by overwriting the previous commit?

I have made the changes in the file and pushed in a repo. But still, previous commits shows my password information. Also, I am not interested in creating a new repo and deleting the old one(unless I have no other choice).

I would be glad if I get some help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Completely remove file from all Git repository commit history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307828/completely-remove-file-from-all-git-repository-commit-history) - this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/23188613/7505395 ccovers it.

Comment: Before you do anything else, _**change your password**_. The one you uploaded is forever compromised.

Comment: @Chris yes I have changed my password. Thanks

Comment: @PatrickArtner Thank you so much for responding. But the problem is I have hardcoded the password in the file which handles the main logic of my application. So I cannot delete that file.

Comment: @AkshayC, so un-hardcode it. There are lots of ways to pull configuration in from non source-controlled files, e.g. using [environment variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

GitHub has an article for exactly this. Check it out [here](https://help.github.com/articles/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository/). To sum up the article: you can use either the `git filter-branch` command or the BFG Repo-Cleaner. BFG Repo-Cleaner is easier and faster to use, so I use that. To use BFG Repo-Cleaner follow these steps:

1. [Download](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) the jar file at the project repo or with macos use `brew install bfg`
2. Clone a fresh copy of your repo, using the `--mirror` flag:

`git clone --mirror git://example.com/some-big-repo.git`

if using SSH or

`git clone --mirror https://example.com/some-big-repo.git`

if using HTTPS.

This is a bare repository so you won't be able to see your files but it will be a full copy of your repository with all commits.

3. You can then use the following command to delete specific files from previous commits:

`java -jar bfg.jar --delete-files [FILE NAME]  --no-blob-protection  my-repo.git`

or if installed to the PATH

`bfg --delete-files [FILE NAME]  --no-blob-protection  my-repo.git`

or to delete a password from an old commit

`bfg --replace-text passwords.txt`

4. Before pushing back up to your repo, check that the repo history has changed by going into your git repo folder and running the following command:

`git reflog expire --expire=now --all && git gc --prune=now --aggressive`

and then

`git gc`

to strip out unwanted data that you don't want to push back up to your repo.

5. Once your happy, push back up to your remote repo by running `git push` - note that, because you used the `--mirror` flag when cloning your repo, when you push back to your repo, you will also push back reference changes.

To read up more about BFG Repo-Cleaner, visit this [link](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/).

Comment: This is a comment (a good one, never mind). Answers should never be link-only. See  [why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)  An answer should be valid even if the link goes down.

Comment: Thank you for editing and responding to feedback your answer is much more acceptable for this site, and suits the Q&A format. :)

Comment: Thank you, Patrick. I appreciate your efforts. I have to read this in detail. But I need that file which has password. Because that file handles main logic of my application. So I can't delete that file.

Comment: Hi Akshay C. I answered the question and here's a link to an answer which answers your question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2397905

Comment: @PritamSangani Thank you so much for the detailed information on BFG Repo-Cleaner. But in this case, it won't be useful for me, because the password is saved in the same file which handles the main logic for the app. So I cannot delete this file. Is there a way to delete the file and upload a new one by overwriting the previous commit?

Comment: You should keep all passwords in a separate file. Then you should commit your new file without passwords and then follow the steps in the answer.

Comment: Sorry never mind, I think I should read it carefully. I am a newbie to this.

Comment: You can use the BFG Repo Cleaner to delete your previous commit history so the old file will not be visible

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you so much, sir. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

first take a copy of the file(ie `app.py`)

remove the file(replace `PATH-TO-YOUR-FILE-WITH-SENSITIVE-DATA` with `path/to/app.py`) from git history(you also need to push the repo if you cloned from a remote repository):

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter \
  "git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch PATH-TO-YOUR-FILE-WITH-SENSITIVE-DATA" \
  --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
git push --force --verbose --dry-run
git push --force
```

now remove the passwords from `app.py` file and move it to git repo, then `add` and `commit`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative and quick workaround to change sensible data without removing files.

```
# Sync with the remote master
git pull

# Force your clone to look like HEAD
git reset --hard

# AGAIN, A WARNING: This can really break stuff!

# Run your filter branch command, replacing all instances of "password" with "your_password"
# The example looks for Ruby files ("*.rb"), you can change this to match your needs
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'git ls-files -z "*.rb" |xargs -0 perl -p -i -e "s#(password)#your_password#g"' -- --all

# Overwrite your master with local changes
git push origin master --force
```

Source: https://palexander.posthaven.com/remove-a-password-from-gits-commit-history-wi