# What is the most secure way to store authentication data when deploying an app in Heroku by GitHub repo?

Tags: python, github, heroku, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I'm attempting to deploy a Pythonic Telegram bot from my GitHub repository using Heroku's service.
Telegram's API includes an API token, which I keep as a secret in my Github repository.
How could I deploy the software that was linked to GitHub and insert the app's credentials?
I don't want my credentials to be included in the codebase.
What is the safest and easy way to handle the situation?

Answer (score 0):

Basically use config files and .gitignore, but the question is answered in much greater detail here [What is the best practice for dealing with passwords in git repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397822/what-is-the-best-practice-for-dealing-with-passwords-in-git-repositories)